# Transform integration regions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, simplex, calculus

$$
\int_0^L{dx_1
\int_0^{x_1}{dx_2
\cdots
\int_0^{x_{n-1}}{dx_n f(|x_i-x_j|)}
}
}
=\frac{1}{n!}
\int_0^L{dx_1
\int_0^{L}{dx_2
\cdots
\int_0^{L}{dx_n f(|x_i-x_j|)}
}
}
$$
where $f(|x_i-x_j|)$ means a function dependent on all possible $|x_i-x_j|\,,i\ne j$.

What is the condition of $f$ that satisfies this identity? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is not $L^n/n!$ instead of $1/n!$  ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom Sure..